# Map fragment in a bottom navigation bar - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I new on programming android apps. I want to display a map in one of the fragments that I created for a bottom navigation bar. However, I'm not sure what I should include in the the MainActivity.java, the fragment_map.xml, and the MapFragment.java.
I share my code to see if anyone could please help me to figure it out what I should include in each one.
Thanks :)

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the layout file as the content view.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get a handle to the fragment and register the callback.
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private void getMapAsync(MapFragment mapFragment) {
    }


    private void setContentView(int activity_main) {
    }

    // Get a handle to the GoogleMap object and display marker.
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Marker"));
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Fragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    private Fragment storyFragment = new StoryFragment();
    private Fragment infoFragment = new InfoFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.body_container, mapFragment, null).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.body_container, storyFragment, null).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.body_container, infoFragment, null).commit();
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        //bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.mapsFragment);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    }

    private NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener navListener = new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_map:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.body_container, mapFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_story:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.body_container, storyFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_info:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.body_container, infoFragment).commit();
                    break;


    }

                return true;
            }
        };


    }
```

fragment_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: [Guide on Google Map fragments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm).